# How to set values of all element in array with loop conditional?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `listProduct`. I want to loop through all element in this array and set condition `itemID` in `listProduct` is 0 will print a text.

Like this:

```
foreach (listProduct as $item)
   if($item->proCode == 0)
      echo "true";
   elseif ($item->proCode == 1)
      echo "false";
   else
      echo "nothing";
   endif
```

Problem is:

It will loop through this array, and this only compares the last item of an array with conditional.

If I add a `break` after `echo` command, it will fail at first element of an array.

I had a GUI when I clicked a button `Edit`. I want to check at this `proCode` is 0. It only loads any element, if `proCode` is 1, it loads another element.

Have any method to loop through sequence element in an array.

**Updated 1:**

I think my question is unclear.

So, my case needs resolve with `id`. This mean, when to click an `Edit` button, get `id` to check in conditional.

Don't need any loop in this case.

Thanks, #FrayneKonok, #Barmar and #Abolarinstephen.

Comment: You want to break at `if($item->proCode == 0)`?? As you said about `itemID` is not present inside the loop, also you forgot to end the loop.

Comment: I want to break at any position in this loop.

Comment: @FrayneKonok This mean: I had a GUI when I clicked a button `Edit`. I want to check at this `proCode` is 0. It only loads any element, If `proCode` is 1, it load another item.

Comment: DID you try this: `if($item->proCode == 0){
     echo "true";
     break;
}`

Comment: If you want to continue for the `proCode == 1` then you can use continue instead of break.

Comment: I know my problem. When to click a button `Edit` rows. I'm getting this `id` and check with conditional. Don't use `foreach` in this case. 
Thanks @FrayneKonok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125304/discussion-between-frayne-konok-and-vn-lc).

Comment: Where are you getting your Id from, a database?

Comment: Of course, I getting `id` from a database.

Comment: Have you written the Db query?

Comment: Base on your answer: `id` to resolve my problem and its success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

The array must have an index 'proCode'

I am assuming this is a 2D array

$id = $_GET['id'];

```
if ($listProduct[$i]['proCode'] == 0):
    echo "True";
elseif ($listProduct[$i]['proCode'] == 1):
    echo "False";
 else:
     echo "Nothing";
 endif;
```

Comment: I had a GUI when I clicked a button Edit. I want to check at this proCode is 0. It only loads any element, if proCode is 1, it loads another element.

Comment: Please can you explain what you really need in detail.

Comment: What you really do for the OP??

Comment: I have comment to @FrayneKonok. I know my problem. When to click a button `Edit` rows. I'm getting this `id` and check with conditional. Don't use `foreach` in this case. 
Thanks @FrayneKonok and #Abolarin stephen..

Comment: Why aren't you accessing `$listProduct[$i]->proCode`?

Comment: Your answer not correct with my case but it provides a suggest to resolve my problem.

Comment: I will update my question. You should edit your answer to correct with my question. Thanks @Abolarinstephen

Comment: Okay Would do that